# Facebook API Implementation in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-graph-api

I have an application. I have created a facebook page for it . Now when I look at the Facebook API , It asks me this

1)**Select how your app integrates with Facebook**

**Website with Facebook Login(Log in to my website using Facebook.),
App on Facebook                 (Use my app inside Facebook.com.),
Mobile Web                  (Bookmark my web app on Facebook mobile.),
Native iOS App                 ( Publish from my iOS app to Facebook.),
Native Android App         ( Publish from my Android app to Facebook.),
Page Tab                   (Build a custom tab for Facebook Pages.**),

2)What exactly I want to do is when my user opens up my app for the first time, I want to use his credentials and post using my app on his behalf.
3)I want to implement the API so that after the user allows my app to connect to his profile, I use my app while he shares anything through my app to post on his behalf.
Kindly help me in all these circumstances with the perfect code as I am novoice to OAuth

Comment: Was there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: I did.  There isn't a question, just a list of things you are doing.

Comment: kindly answer point 1. what to choose amongst them

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on official Facebook C# SDK Sample for Windows Phone 7

https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-windows-phone-sample

Comment: i have VS2012 Installed.My app is a 7.1 based.i used NuGet to install the package of Facebook C# SDK Sample By OutCurve Foundation v 6.1.4 , the problem is its not installing giving errors like incompatible binaries

Comment: Successfully uninstalled 'Facebook 6.1.4'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'Facebook 6.1.4'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.